# SMS using built in android messaging system which uses the Mobile Carrier

Tags: android

i'm working on an android application to send sms to other mobile numbers using android built in messaging system.....can anyone guide me how to do it???

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SmsManager.sendTextMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello